# What is the point of URLConnection.getHeaderFields() returning a Map<String,List<String>>

Tags: java, http

I can't see the value in this method returning a Map<String List<String>> instead of simply Map<String, String>

I was expecting Map<String List<String>> to be of value when a web server returns more than one value in a given header. It's legal for several values to be returned as a comma delimited list. I've seen this most often with Cache-Control. I'd expect each value to be an item in the list. However, that's not the case:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class URLConnectionDemo {
  private static final String DEFAULT_URL = "http://stackoverflow.com";
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    URL url; 
    URLConnection urlConnection;
    try { 
      url = new URL((args.length==0) ? DEFAULT_URL : args[0]); 
      urlConnection = url.openConnection();  
      Map<String, List<String>> headerMap = urlConnection.getHeaderFields();
      System.out.printf("Header count = %d\n", headerMap.size());
      for(String key:headerMap.keySet()){
        System.out.printf("%s:\n", key);
        List<String> valuesList = headerMap.get(key);
        for(String value:valuesList){
          System.out.printf("  %s\n", value);
        }
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Header count = 19
null:
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
....many other headers....
Cache-Control:
  public, max-age=7
```

The Cache-Control values are just returned as a single String.

So, are there any circumstances where the header value List<String> is of any use?

**Solution:**

I'm using a servlet on Tomcat to try & generate duplicated http response headers.

In the servlet code, using repeated calls to 
HttpServletResponse.addHeader()
with duplicated header names doesn't work. All the header values get consolidated into a single comma separated value.

However, that's not allowed for adding cookies. If I use 
HttpServletResponse.addCookie()
several times, I get several distinct Set-Cookie headers. These do indeed end up as distinct Strings in the List.

Comment: If you're asking why the API was designed this way, no-one will be able to have a definite answer, making the question opinion-based. Please refer to [Is asking “why” on language specifications still considered as “primarily opinion-based” if it can have official answers?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323382/1743880) and [Is it subjective to ask about why something wasn't implemented in the language?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/293819/1743880)

Comment: Technically speaking, it's permissible to repeat HTTP header keys. Semantically, it's equivalent to comma concatenation.

Comment: @Tunaki In this case there is a simple objective reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
field_name: field_value1, field_value2, field_value3
```

in HTTP Header gives 1 string in the list of corresponding map entry, while semantically equivalent

```
field_name: field_value1
field_name: field_value2
field_name: field_value3
```

will give 3 strings.

However not all values with the same field name may be combined into field values list. For example, in [RFC 7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230) we may read

> Note: In practice, the "Set-Cookie" header field ([RFC6265]) often
> appears multiple times in a response message and does not use the
> list syntax, violating the above requirements on multiple header
> fields with the same name.  Since it cannot be combined into a
> single field-value, recipients ought to handle "Set-Cookie" as a
> special case while processing header fields.  (See Appendix A.2.3
> of [Kri2001] for details.)

Comment: True, but the text you are citing is from RFC 7230, not RFC 2616.

Answer (score 7):

The reason is simply that HTTP headers can be both repeated and multi-valued.

Comment: If there were *multiple* Cache-Control response header fields, then the list would be supposed to contain multiple strings.

Comment: Julian: Do you know of any site returning repeated headers in order to test this? I've been trying to produce such a response via a servlet on Tomcat, using duplicated HttpServletResponse.addHeader() calls, but by the time I view them in Firefox, they've all been consolidated into a single comma separated list.

Comment: rhg: it might be that the Firefox developer tools do not display this properly. Try telnet or redbot.org

Comment: @twisted Or it might be that `addHeader()` already consolidates them.